# RegionIntersection Using an Arrow and a Circle

Tags: graphics, regions

This works:

```
RegionIntersection[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], Circle[{0, 0}, 0.6`, {30 °, 80 °}]]
```

returning a point:

```
Point[{0.424264, 0.424264}]
```

But this doesn't:

```
RegionIntersection[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], Circle[{0, 0}, 0.6`, {30 °, 80 °}]]
```

It returns:

> ```
> RegionIntersection::reg: Arrow[{{0,0},{1,1}}] is not a correctly specified region.
> ```

Any thoughts? Is this something we would like to work?

Comment: Do you have concrete examples of situations where it would be useful to be able to use `Arrow` as a region?

Comment: @C.E. I was constructing the bisector of an angle of two arrows that met at vertex A. I was creating an image that shows how to do this with a ruler and a compass for my students.

Comment: I'd like to thank my colleagues for their excellent help.

Answer (score 4):

You could include a special treatment for `Arrow` whenever it is found as an argument to `RegionIntersection`, so that it is converted into the corresponding `Line` object:

```
Unprotect[RegionIntersection];
RegionIntersection[OrderlessPatternSequence[Arrow[pts_], region_]] := 
    RegionIntersection[Line[pts], region]
Protect[RegionIntersection];

RegionIntersection[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], Circle[{0, 0}, 0.6`, {30 °, 80 °}]]
(* Out: Point[{0.424264, 0.424264}] *)
```

... or in the opposite order (thanks to `OrderlessPatternSequence`):

```
RegionIntersection[Circle[{0, 0}, 0.6`, {30 °, 80 °}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]
(* Out: Point[{0.424264, 0.424264}] *)
```

Honestly, however, I don't see much of a use for this apart from one-off convenience.

Comment: +1 ! i added a slightly modified version of your answer separately

Answer (score 3):

You can just use rules,e.g.:

```
roi = {Circle[{0, 0}, 0.6`, {30 \[Degree], 80 \[Degree]}],Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}
Graphics[{roi, PointSize[0.02], Red,RegionIntersection @@ (roi /. Arrow[x__] :> Line[x])}]
```

[image]

Comment: Even simpler: just use `Arrow -> Line` as the replacement rule.

Answer (score 2):

a slight variant of @MarcoB 's answer (we can do without `Unprotect`):

```
roi = {Circle[{0, 0}, 0.6`, {30 \[Degree], 80 \[Degree]}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]};
SetAttributes[regInt, HoldAllComplete];
regInt[OrderlessPatternSequence[region_, arrow : Arrow[_]]] := 
RegionIntersection[region, Line @@ arrow];

Graphics[{roi, PointSize[0.02], Red, regInt @@ roi}]
```